Can we tune chemical potential by electrostatic gating in solids?
I often hear that chemical potential in solids can be controlled by electrostatically gating the sample besides other methods such as chemically doping the sample. What are the limitations of electrostatic gating? For example, is it easier for thin films and hard for bulk 3D samples? Any difference between (semi)metals and insulators?

What do you mean by ‘gating’ ?

Do you mean like protein gates or maybe a carbon filter? I think I saw machine learning being applied to design where holes should be, optimizing for something in chemistry. Looked like a cheese.

@JonCuster Maybe 'gating' refers to the gate in a field effect transistor.

Yes electrostatic gating is essentially confined to thin films or very thin flakes of materials. This is a relatively good review https://www.annualreviews.org/docserver/fulltext/matsci/44/1/annurev-matsci-070813-113407.pdf?expires=1723247870&id=id&accname=guest&checksum=6D61EEFE68282F92BB532F9A22E0FEF8#:~:text=Electrostatic%20gating%20is%20an%20interfacial,densities%20found%20in%20many%20materials.
